# How Can I Remove The Blue Tint On The QTreeWidget Item Icon

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem, qicon

[image]```

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from datetime import *
import sqlite3
import sys
import time
import datetime


class MyDelegateTreeWidget(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self):
        QItemDelegate.__init__(self)

    def sizeHint(self, option, index):
        return QSize(50, 60)


class CustomizeTreeWidget(QTreeWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setColumnCount(2)
        self.sizeHintForRow(50)
        self.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)

        inventoryTreeWidgetFont = QFont('Helvetica', 8)
        inventoryTreeWidgetFont.setBold(True)
        self.setFont(inventoryTreeWidgetFont)
        self.header().setMinimumSectionSize(2)
        self.header().resizeSection(0, 150)
        self.header().resizeSection(1, 2)
        self.header().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.header().swapSections(1, 0)
        self.expandToDepth(True)
        self.setHeaderHidden(True)
        self.setAnimated(True)
        self.setUniformRowHeights(True)
        self.setStyleSheet('QTreeWidget {border: none;  border-image: none; background-color: rgb(240,240,240); color: rgb(80,80,80)}'
        'QTreeWidget::item:hover {border: none; border-image: none; background-color: rgb(180,180,180); color: rgb(50,50,50)}'
        'QTreeWidget::item:selected {border: none;  border-image: none; background-color: rgb(39,39,37); color: rgb(245,245,245)}'
        'QTreeWidget::branch:hover {border: none;  border-image: none; background: rgb(180,180,180); color: rgb(50,50,50)}'
        'QTreeWidget::branch::closed::has-children {image: url(TDLSystemPictures/OtherIcons/rightArrowIcon3.png); '
        'icon-size: 1px}'
        'QTreeWidget::branch::open:has-children {image: url(TDLSystemPictures/OtherIcons/downArrowIcon3.png);}'
        'QTreeWidget::branch:selected {border: none;  border-image: none; background: rgb(39,39,37); color: rgb(245,245,245)}')

        self.setRootIsDecorated(True)
        self.setIconSize(QSize(35, 30))

        treeWidgetDelegate = MyDelegateTreeWidget()
        self.setItemDelegate(treeWidgetDelegate)

class SystemMainPage(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.move(400, 150)
        self.setMinimumWidth(1200)
        self.setMinimumHeight(800)
        self.setStyleSheet('QWidget {background-color: rgb(200,200,200)}')
        self.setWindowTitle('Sample')
        self.mainPageLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.mainPageLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.mainPageLayout.setSpacing(0)

        home_SubMenuTreeWidget = CustomizeTreeWidget()

        ###########################################################
        # ================================ Tree Widget Item (Start)
        ###########################################################
        #
        # ================== Client Masterfile
        sampleIcon = QIcon('Icon1.png')
        clientMasterfileContent = QTreeWidgetItem(home_SubMenuTreeWidget, ['Item 1'])
        clientMasterfileContent.setIcon(0, sampleIcon)
        clientMasterfileContent.icon(25)
        clientMasterfileContentLight = QFrame()
        clientMasterfileContentLight.setFixedWidth(2)
        clientMasterfileContentLight.setStyleSheet('QFrame {border: none; background-color: rgb(37,39,45)}')
        home_SubMenuTreeWidget.setItemWidget(clientMasterfileContent, 1, clientMasterfileContentLight)

        createClient_Content = QTreeWidgetItem(clientMasterfileContent, ['Item 1- A'])

        # ================== Billing
        color1 = QColor(255, 35, 35)
        billingContent = QTreeWidgetItem(home_SubMenuTreeWidget, ['Item 2'])
        billingContent.setIcon(0, QIcon('Icon2.png'))
        billingContentLight = QFrame()
        billingContentLight.setFixedWidth(2)
        billingContentLight.setStyleSheet('QFrame {border: none; background-color: rgb(37,39,45)}')
        home_SubMenuTreeWidget.setItemWidget(billingContent, 1, billingContentLight)

        self.mainPageLayout.addWidget(home_SubMenuTreeWidget)
        self.setLayout(self.mainPageLayout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    homeApplication = QApplication(sys.argv)
    homeApplication.setStyle('Fusion')
    homeMainWindow = SystemMainPage()
    homeMainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(homeApplication.exec_())

# ====== Creating Customized Tree Widget (Start)
```

Edited: Code can be run but I did not include the sample picture or icon. Any pictures will do. Please replace the "QIcon(Icon1.png)" with proper pictures.

Every time a TreeWidgetItem is clicked, it doesn't matter what the icon of the color is, it will always give a blue tint on it.

Wanted Result:
I wanted to control the Icon's color, like we do on stylesheets where we can configure the RGB. Or it will be fine if the icon's color will not be changed.

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: Already added a functional code.